# Bookmark multiple files updated in shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

My shiny app has a module to allow users to upload an external .csv file. The app will call this module twice, ie user can upload 2 files but it is optional (they can choose upload it once, or none at all).

Regardless, I want users to be able to save any files they upload and restore at a later stage.

My code seems to work if I upload at least 2 files, but it doesnt work if only one file is uploaded. This is the error I have:
[image]

Is there a way to make the bookmark button work?

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

capitalizerUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  wellPanel(
    fileInput(ns("file"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

capitalizerServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,function(input,output,session){
               
  output$out <- renderText({
    toupper(input$file$name)
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    fread(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  onBookmark(function(state) {
    state$values$data <- data()
  })
  
  onRestored(function(state) {
    data <<- reactive(state$values$data)
  })
  }) 
}

# Main app code
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    capitalizerUI("tc"),
    capitalizerUI("tz"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  capitalizerServer("tc")
  capitalizerServer("tz")
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Comment: I found a way to fix it myself. Look like I need to add conditional statements in the server to avoid fread being trigger if no file is uploaded.  data <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$file)) {
        NULL
      } else {
        fread(input$file$datapath)
      }
    })